# While loop logic not working on my code, cant figure it out

Tags: c++

Im having issues on how to make the while loop work on my code (C++), can you please help? I want the user to be asked a question and if the answer is "si" then to execute what I have for the if statements. If answer is no, then skip the while loop and execute the last code. Im getting an error after all the input, just an endless loop of letters.
Any hints on how I can fix it will be very appreciated! Thank you.

```
int main()
{   
    int a, b, c, d, total, promedio;
    
    string siNo;

    
    cout << "Ingresar nota 1: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout <<"Ingrese segunda nota: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Ingrese tercera nota: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Ingresar nota 4: ";
    cin >> d;

    cout<<endl;

    cout << "Desea eximirse? ";
    cin >> siNo;

    total = (a+b+c+d)/4;
    promedio = (a+b+c)/3;

    while (siNo != "no"){

    if(promedio >= 85){
        cout << "Si está eximido, su promedio es: " + promedio;
    }
    if(promedio < 85){
        cout << "No está eximido, su promedio de los 3 parciales es:" + promedio;
        }

    }
    
    cout << "Su nota final es " + total;
    
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) where inside the loop the value of `siNo` can change. Does it really make sense to have a loop here?

Comment: Additionally confirm that *Integer Division* is intended with `total = (a+b+c+d)/4;` and `promedio = (a+b+c)/3;`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes you are right, I should change this to double, thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Im a beginner, im trying to find the best way. What would you suggest? thanks.

Comment: Changing the variables to a double will give me this error:  "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type". I have no idea what this means. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Use a plain `if` statement instead of a loop?

Comment: `int a, b, c, d;` and `double total, promedio;` then `total = (a+b+c+d)/4.;` (note the `'.'` after `4`) and likewise `promedio = (a+b+c)/3.;` Now `cout << "Si está eximido, su promedio es: " << promedio;` (and fix the rest of the outputs the same way)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any exit loop statement inside your while loop that is why it is running in infinite loop

```
while (siNo != "no"){
    if(promedio >= 85){
        cout << "Si está eximido, su promedio es: " + promedio;
        break; // just add this line
    }
    if(promedio < 85){
        cout << "No está eximido, su promedio de los 3 parciales es:" + promedio;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the break, so loop will stop and program ends without solving the program.

Comment: use "<< promedio; " instead of " + promedio;" you can't concatinate a string and an integer, I forgot to mention that sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop:

```
while (siNo != "no") {

    if(promedio >= 85){
        cout << "Si está eximido, su promedio es: " + promedio;
    }
    if(promedio < 85) {
        cout << "No está eximido, su promedio de los 3 parciales es:" + promedio;
    }
}
```

Since nothing changes `siNo` after the cout statements, it's going to keep evaluating `(siNo != "no")` to be true.

Comment: Ok im trying to understand. So if user inputs no it will go into an endless loop, how would I make it true? not sure how to ask the right question :s

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a loop is necessary here

```
// if answer is equal to "si"
if (siNo == "si") { 
   if(promedio >= 85){ 
   } // continue here
} 

// else is not required 
// if you don't want to do anything when answer is no

return 0;
```

A simple if statement will do the trick for ya.

Comment: Oh thanks, yes this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions and comments, it was definitely easier to use ifs, no need for a while loop. Here is how I solved it:

```
 if (siNo == "si")
{
    if(promedio >= 85)
    {
    cout << "Si está eximido, su promedio es: " << promedio << endl;
    cout << "Su nota para el cuarto parcial es: " << promedio << endl;
    }   
    else { 
     cout << "No está eximido, su promedio de los 3 parciales es:"<< promedio << endl;
    }
}

if (siNo == "no")
{    
    cout << "Ingresar nota 4: ";
    cin >> d;
        cout << "Su nota final es " << total;
}

 return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hey thank you all for your responses. I finally managed to make it work with your tips and using for loops. Here is the code, hope it helps others with same questions:

```
int main() {

double precios[5];
int cantidades[5];

double precioMasAlto = 0;
int cantidadMinima;
double total = 0;
int codigosProducto[5];
int codigoProducto = 0;
int codCantidadMasBaja = 0;

// 1.  ingreso de datos
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    cout << "Ingrese codigo de producto " << i << endl;
    cin >> codigosProducto[i];
    cout << "Ingresar precio de producto " << i << endl;
    cin >> precios[i];
    cout << "Ingresar cantidad del producto " << i << endl;
    cin>> cantidades[i];
}

cantidadMinima = cantidades[0];
    

// 2. cual de los productos tiene el precio mas alto

  for(int posicion = 0; posicion < 5; posicion++){
      if(precios[posicion] > precioMasAlto){
          precioMasAlto = precios[posicion];
          codigoProducto = codigosProducto[posicion];
      }
  }
  
cout << "El producto con mayor precio es el Producto " << codigoProducto << ", cuyo precio es " << precioMasAlto <<endl;
// 3. cual de los productos tiene menor existencias

for(int posicion = 0; posicion < 5; posicion++){
      if(cantidades[posicion] < cantidadMinima ){
          cantidadMinima = cantidades[posicion];
          codigoProducto = codigosProducto[posicion];
        }
    }
    
cout << "El producto con menor existencia es el Producto " << codigoProducto << ", con una existencia actual de " << cantidadMinima  << endl; 

// 4. total de productos
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     total += cantidades[i];
}

cout << "El total de productos x cantidad es " << total;



return 0;
```

}